# Is WSDL supports both SOAP Web-services && Restful Web-services

Tags: java, rest, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on web-services , in my project i have a scope to use both SOAP && Restful  web-services.

Can i use WSDL for  both SOAP && Restful Web-services.

Comment: yes for soap and somehow manageable for rest. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907114/why-rest-does-not-have-a-wsdl-unlike-soap and https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/